# Limit problem that i could not solve

Tags: limits

please help  in cualculating this limit :
$$
  \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\ln|\frac{2}{x} - 2|}{x^2 - 3 x + 2} 
$$

Comment: Welcome to [Math Stackexhange](http://math.stackexchange.com) . Please show us your attempt so the community can help you better . It is also ensures that the user is doing some efforts in solving the problem and is not using the site for others to solve their homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here L'Hospital is surely a quick way after some simplification.

For $x\to 2$ you can write

\begin{eqnarray}\frac{\ln|\frac{2}{x} - 2|}{x^2 - 3 x + 2}
& = & \frac{\ln 2 +\ln(x-1) - \ln x}{x^2-3x+2}\\
& \stackrel{L'Hosp.}{\sim} & \frac{\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac 1x}{2x-3} \\
& = & \frac{1}{x(x-1)(2x-3)} \stackrel{x\to2}{\longrightarrow} \frac 12
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hey my problem says not to use  l'hospital  rule

Comment: @AlexMason  You didn't even write in your question that L'Hospital is not allowed.  So, how should anybody know it?

Comment: Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ taking values suficiently close to 2 we have $\frac{2}{x}-2 <0$ so that:
$$\frac{\ln |\frac{2}{x}-2|}{x^{2}-3x+2} = \frac{\ln(2-\frac{2}{x})}{x^{2}-3x+2}$$
We can now apply L'Hospital:
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\ln |\frac{2}{x}-2|}{x^{2}-3x+2} = \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{(2x-3)(2-\frac{2}{x})}(\frac{2}{x^{2}}) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write it as:
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\ln|\frac{2}{x} - 2|}{x^2 - 3 x + 2}=\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{x-1}\cdot \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\ln|2-\frac{2}{x}|}{x-2}=
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\ln (1+1-\frac{2}{x})}{(1-\frac2x)}\cdot \frac1x=\frac12,$$
where:
$$2-\frac2x>0,x=2\pm \epsilon;\\
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

By standard limits we have

$$\frac{\ln|\frac{2}{x} - 2|}{x^2 - 3 x + 2}=\frac{\ln (x-1)-\ln \frac x 2}{(x-2)(x-1)}=\frac{\ln (1+(x-2))-\ln \left(1+\left(\frac x2-1\right)\right)}{(x-2)(x-1)}=$$

$$=\frac1{x-1}\frac{\ln (1+(x-2))}{x-2}-\frac1{2(x-1)}\frac{\ln \left(1+\left(\frac x2-1\right)\right)}{\frac x 2 -1} \to 1-\frac12=\frac12$$